# Удаление тега <a> с помощью jquery, оставив при этом анкор ссылки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно удалить саму ссылку, оставив текст, который её описывает. Грубо говоря, очистить текст от гиперссылок. Как реализуется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("a").replaceWith(function () { return $(this).contents() })
```

Answer (score 3):

уж извините, но без жуквери, если надо с ним, см ответ @Qwertiy

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => {
   a.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(a.textContent), a);
   a.remove();
 })
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com">google.com</a> hello <a href="https://yandex.ru">yandex.ru</a>
```

Comment: У qsa есть свой forEach - не особо полезно его спредить.

Comment: @Qwertiy да я привык что он не везде, хотя и спред тоже

Comment: Немного не это подразумевал, нужно, чтобы в DOM не было    <a>.

Comment: @BlackFire ок, я не так понял вопрос, сейчас поправим

Comment: `a.textContent` - если в ссылке была разметка, она уничтожится.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, надо полагать в общем случае это критично, но и createTextNode не съест разметку

Comment: _"но и createTextNode не съест разметку"_ - не понял.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну я добавляю только текстовый узел, туда не влезет разметка - станет текстом

Comment: Значит "не" было лишнее в комменте. А вообще: `while (a.firstChild) a.parentNode.insertBefore(a.firstChild, a);`